# How to make onActivityResult get called on nested fragment from viewpager

Tags: android, android-viewpager, onactivityresult, android-nested-fragment

This is a famous problem of getting result from activity to a nested fragment, the activity could send the result to only the Fragment that has been attached directly to Activity but not the nested one. That's the reason why onActivityResult of nested fragment would never been called no matter what.
In my case i have one activity that contains one fragment which has a viewPager with bunch of fragments.
In one of this fragments of the viewPager i try to start a camera intent, the result returned by this intent is never sent to the last fragment, i tried severals answers that i found but none of them is robust, one of the solutions was to create an EventBus object to diffuse the resultCode from activity to all the fragments but it doesn't work for this case, any help??

Answer (score 0):

I might have a working solution for you since I used to be in a very similar situation.

In short terms I **stopped relying** on `Fragment`'s `onActivityResult()` and implemented a working logic myself.

The only `onActivityResult()` you should trust is the one of your `Activity`.

You may create an `interface`like this one

```
public interface ActivityResultDispatcher {
    // Pass anything you want, Bundle, Intent, ecc...
    // For the sake of simplicity I'm using Bundle...
    public void dispatchResultData(final Bundle data);
}
```

and have your `Fragment` classes implement it.

The communication between your `Activity` and your **primary** `Fragment`should be very easy that you can do something like this (in your `Activity`):

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    final Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    // put data inside Bundle
    this.primaryFrament.dispatchResultData(bundle);
}
```

Now, your primary `Fragment` is the one that holds the `ViewPager` with the other `Frament` classes.

So in your primary `Fragment` you will do:

```
@Override public void dispatchResultData(final Bundle data) {

    for (int i = 0; i < MyViewPager.NUM_FRAGMENTS; i++) {
        final ActivityResultDispatcher subFragment = (ActivityResultDispatcher) this.retrieveFragment(i);

        // some fragments in ViewPager may be dynamically deleted
        if (subFragment != null) {
            subFragment.dispatchResultData(data);
        } 
    }
}
```

The function `retrieveFragment(final int position)` is a very cozy piece of code I had found on the web.

An implementation for a `ViewPager` works like this:

```
public Fragment retrieveFragment(final int position) {
    return this.fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag("android:switcher:" + R.id.my_pager_id + ":" + position);
}
```

All your active `Fragment` classes in the `ViewPager` will receive the `Bundle` and you can decide what to do with it.

You may pass more information to the dispatcher, such as

```
public void dispatchResultData(final Bundle data, final int requestCode);
```

and have your `Fragment` decide if it should answer to the function call.

You have basically built a complete fully-working `onActivityResult()` utility and can be sure that all of your `Fragments` (if instantiated) will receive the result.